# Assert pattern match in phoenix tests

Tags: unit-testing, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm testing a phoenix/elixir application, and I find myself using something like the following an awful lot.

```
player = insert(:player)
assert [%Player{id: x}] = Players.site_players(player.site_id)
assert x == player.id
```

This accomplishes the things I want, mainly it ensures that Players.site_players/1 returns an array and that array includes the player. I feel like this could be done more concisely. Any suggestions?

Comment: The best way of DRYing it would be to remove all these tests. You are testing `DB` functionality and `Ecto` functionality. It makes no sense. Tests in _your_ application should test _your application_, not `Ecto`, that has it’s own tests.

Comment: I'm testing that my code (in this case, the site_players method) asks Ecto to do the appropriate things. This is the simplest place I encounter the pattern I want to clean up, chosen for illustrative purposes. In other places it runs against more complicated code.

Comment: Not at all. `defmodule Players, do: def site_players(id), do: %Player{id: id}` implementation of `Player` _would unsurprisingly pass this test_. Which basically means you test the **implementation details**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how concise you were expecting, but here's how to do the same thing in one less line of code:

```
%Player{id: id, site_id: site_id} = insert(:player)
assert [%Player{id: ^id}] = Players.site_players(site_id)
```

As you may already know, you cannot have a function call along with the pin operator, only a local variable name, which is why we extract the id into a variable in the first line.

The first line can also be the following if you want:

```
%{id: id, site_id: site_id} = insert(:player)
```